# Similar matrix computation using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to find a similar matrix B to a 3 X 3 matrix :A using a random invertible matrix P .
B = P_inv.A.P

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import linalg as LA
from numpy.linalg import inv

A = np.random.randint(1,10,9).reshape(3,3)
P = np.random.randn(3,3)
P_inv = inv(P)
eig1 = LA.eigvalsh(A)
eig1 = np.sort(eig1)

B1 = P_inv.dot(A)
B = B1.dot(P)
eig2 = LA.eigvalsh(B)
eig2 = np.sort(eig2)

print(np.round(eig1 ,3))
print(np.round(eig2,3))
```

However ,I ntoice that eig1 & eig2 are never equal.
What am I missing, or is it a numerical error ?

Thanks

Kedar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `eigvalsh`, which requires that the matrix be real symmetric (or complex Hermitian), which your randomly generated matrix is not.

Deleting the `h` and using `eigvals` instead fixes this.